# With a WMS server Url, how to know it is a Web map service or a Web map tile service?

Tags: openlayers, wms

I need to add wms map in my project, and the url of wms server will be provided by users.

Are there any ways to know the type of server (wms or wmts) with the url proposed by users ? Or to know that the server supports tiles or not ?

I want to know this because in Openlayers3, there are two functions to getMap: ol.source.ImageWMS and ol.source.TileWMS. I think I need to know the type of server before calling the right function ol3.

Comment: In Openlayers 3: ol.source.ImageWMS: 'WMS servers providing single, untiled images'; ol.source.TileWMS: 'WMS servers providing tiles'. And I want to distinguish these two types.

Answer (score 3):

With WMS & WMTS (as with all OGC services) you can ask for the capabilities of the service with the `request=GetCapabilities` request. A WMS will respond with a document starting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE WMT_MS_Capabilities SYSTEM "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/wms/1.1.1/WMS_MS_Capabilities.dtd">
<WMT_MS_Capabilities version="1.1.1" updateSequence="430">
  <Service>
    <Name>OGC:WMS</Name>
```

While a WMTS will respond with:

```
<Capabilities xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wmts/1.0" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wmts/1.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wmts/1.0/wmtsGetCapabilities_response.xsd" version="1.0.0">
  <ows:ServiceIdentification>
    <ows:Title>Web Map Tile Service - GeoWebCache</ows:Title>
    <ows:ServiceType>OGC WMTS</ows:ServiceType>
    <ows:ServiceTypeVersion>1.0.0</ows:ServiceTypeVersion>
```

When asking a WMS for a WMTS capabilities document, it will reply with

```
<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1">
<ServiceException code="InvalidFormat">
    Can't recognize service requested.
</ServiceException></ServiceExceptionReport>
```

Comment: And if it is WMS and you test WMTS it will send an error. URLs to test with  http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=Getcapabilities http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms?SERVICE=WMTS&REQUEST=Getcapabilities

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I am still confused. Here is a url of wmts: http://geoservices.brgm.fr/WMS-C/?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities, which returns a document starting: <WMT_MS_Capabilities version="1.1.1">. And I have another example: https://wms.geo.admin.ch/?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities, which seems support the twp types ...